# prestashop 1.7.1.2 main menu hooked in displaynavfullwidth

Tags: php, css, prestashop

How do i display only depth=0 categories to horizontal line and depth=1 and further categories remain same with original setting in prestashop 1.7 displaynavfullwidth.

So far i have used display: inline and float: left in my custom .css. I got all my categories inline from depth 0 to last depth.

Here is an original categories straight after hook into displayfullwidthnav image.
[image]

After i added my custom.css code

```
.menu .top-menu li{float:left;}
```

The outcomes came like this..[image]

The main categories are in horizontal line as i expected but it changed my sub categories into horizontal line. In simple i want my main categories like image 2 and sub-categories must remain same as picture 1, which is shown clear and nice. Can some one help me i could i achieve this?

Comment: Could you please share your shop url?

Comment: I found my solution and solved my problem. Thank you for your reply.
Here is what i did. It may be helpful to others.

    .menu .top-menu  > li {float:left;};